# turning off automatic stop on exception in vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008

My coworker's installation of visual studio 2008 breaks every time there's an exception, mine doesn't.

We've been looking for how to stop his from doing this but haven't had any luck. The only difference is that mine was initialized for C# while his was initialized for VB.

Other than reinstalling and choosing the option that says "Optimise for C#" when VS2008 sets up the environment for the first time, does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: You don't have to reinstall to change your preferred environment. Just go to `Tools` -> `Import and Export Settings...`, then `Reset all settings`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the Debug menu, choose "Exceptions..." and you can decide when the debugger breaks for each kind of exception - whether it's immediately, or only if it's unhandled, or neither.

See the [MSDN section on exception handling with debugging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x85tt0dd.aspx) for more information.

Comment: Thank you, this is going to smooth things over a lot.